# How can I test if IIRF works?

Tags: mod-rewrite, shared-hosting, iirf

http://www.codeplex.com/IIRF/Thread/List.aspx

My webhost installed IIRF for me and I am convinced that they did not do it correctly. I've tried numerous examples including one that I know works with apache's mod_rewrite but I can't get anything to work with IIRF. Is there rule or configuration option that you guys have that you know of that will show whether or not the thing is working correctly?

Even something like rewrite all urls to anothersite.com will will help me right now. I hope you guys realize the reason I came for your help. I can figure out how to do the rewrite rules on my own but I don't know if the errors are because of me or the webhost. I have limited options as well since I am on a shared webhost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is tested and working with IIRF:

```
RedirectRule ^.*$ http://www.google.com/ [I,R=301]
```

It will match **any** URL and redirect to Google.

Answer (score 7):

The new version of [IIRF](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=iirf), v1.2.16 R3, includes  a StatusUrl directive that will give you a status page if you do an HTTP GET on it.  It looks like this: 
[image: IIRF Status page]

If you get that page, then IIRF is running.

Comment: I think Cheeso is the author of IIRF IIRC so he might say otherwise but don't forget this will only work on the localhost.

Comment: Yes I am the author of IIRF. The IIRF Status page works only a request arriving from localhost *by default*.  You can enable the iirfstatus page to work from any host.